# Mysql restore after system crash

Tags: mysql

My windows operating system crashes but somehow i save mysql5.0 folder.

Now i want to restore my data as well as structure.
This is what i have in mysql5 directory

[image]

And this is inside data dir

[image]

Inside realestate folder i have all the tables .frm files.
Please tell me how to restore data as well as structure.
Thanks

Comment: Few questions would belong on ServerFault more

Comment: In my not recent experience, just putting the data and structure files in the newly installed mysql was enough.